# How can I format a date according to the user's preferences / locale?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a `DateTime`. I would like to format it into a string according to the user's preferred locale / any other system-specific preferences they have set. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to show:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
...
```

When calling these methods, the value of the DateTime object is automatically formatted using the pattern defined by the `DateTimeFormatInfo` property associated with the current culture.